# MacTeX Problem: TexShop unable to find pdflatex in macOS Monterey

Tags: pdftex, texshop, mactex

New user of MacTeX here. I'm on a mac running macOS Monterey 12.5. After installing MacTeX (and checking the package using the MD5 sum) I tried typesetting the LatexTemplate in TeXShop, but get the following error:

`/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex does not exist. TeXShop is a front end for TeX, but you also need a TeX distribution. Perhaps such a distribution was not installed or was removed during a system upgrade. If so, go to http://tug.org/mactex and follow the instructions to install MacTeX or BasicTeX.`

In the finder, if I go to /Library/TeX I can find the texbin alias. But, in terminal, if I run `which pdflatex` it returns `pdflatex not found`. Running `sudo which pdflatex` and typing in my administrator password returns `/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex` as expected.

In TeXShop preferences, my Path Settings under the Engine tab have been set to `/Library/TeX/texbin` and `/usr/local/bin` as suggested elsewhere on tex.stackexchange.

Is there some issue with Library permissions in macOS Monterey? I've enabled full disk access for TeXShop and TeX Live Utility in system preferences but it hasn't helped. I've also removed all my old versions of TeX, the GUI applications, and the TeX Distribution Data Structure and done a complete reinstall of MacTeX but that hasn't helped either.

Comment: Seems like a permissions' problem... I don't use mac but does your user have access to the folder  `/Library/TeX/texbin/` (`ls -l` on the folder command will possibly help to check that).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: What does `which pdflatex` (no `sudo`) give? Do you have special permissions set for `/usr` or `/usr/local`? Did you insatll the full MacTeX?

Comment: Yeah, I suspect it's a permissions problem with the Library folder. `ls -l /Library/TeX/texbin` returns ls: /Library/TeX/texbin: Permission denied
lrwx------  1 root  wheel  29 Aug  9 17:43 /Library/TeX/texbin

Comment: `/usr` and `/usr/local` seem fine, permissions-wise. I don't think the problem lies there. For example, `ls -l /usr/local` returns `drwxr-xr-x` for `/usr/local`.

Is there any way around this? I assumed giving TeXShop full disk access would allow it to access the /Library folder, but it doesn't seem the case.

In case it's helpful, I'm running an administrator account. I also did install the full MacTeX, downloaded from https://www.tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html using Safari and checked using the MD5 sum.

Comment: Also, `which pdflatex` with no `sudo` returns `pdflatex not found`.

Answer (score 1):

Update: it appears that the aliases located at `/Library/TeX/` are broken for some reason, or are otherwise inaccessible to TeXShop due to permissions issues. When I set the (pdf)TeX Path settings in TeXShop to `/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/universal-darwin/` it was able to compile.